# jquery: how to disable dblclick events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, double-click

premise: 
developing a graphic scatterplot (with flotchart.org) I have a js function that dynamically create a  that show a image (button) to realize a user action CLICKING on the button ("pan Left" on the example code here below)

problem:
when the user click fast over the button, an (undesired) double click event is triggered.
How can I disable double click when mouse is over the button (so allowing only single click event) ? In other words: What wrong using unbind or dblclick inthe code here below ?

```
function addButtonPanLeft(x, top, offset) {
    $('<img id="buttonPanLeft" class="navigationbutton" src="../images/pan-left.png" style="left:' + x + 'px;top:' + top + 'px"' + ' title="Pan Left">').appendTo(placeholder).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        panleft();
    });

    // disabilito double click sul bottone
    $('#buttonPanLeft').unbind('dblclick');
}


function addButtonPanRight(x, top, offset) {
    $('<img id="buttonPanRight" class="navigationbutton" src="../images/pan-right.png" style="left:' + x + 'px;top:' + top + 'px"' + ' title="Pan Right">').appendTo(placeholder).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        panright();
    });

    // disabilito double click sul bottone  NON FUNZIONA ??????
    $('#buttonPanRight').dblclick(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        panright();
        log({
            text: "double click",
            type: 'debug'
        });
    });
}
```

many thanks
giorgio

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: As [@Accountant م](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5407848/accountant-%d9%85) has mentioned in the comments, [`unbind`](https://api.jquery.com/unbind/) is now deprecated. Use the similar [`off`](https://api.jquery.com/off/) instead.

`unbind` removes all event handlers, it does not prevent the event from being triggered. What you need to do is *attach* an event handler that stops the event's propagation:

```
$('#buttonPanLeft').unbind('dblclick');
$('#buttonPanLeft').dblclick(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

EDIT: I might have misunderstood your question. In the event that you want to prevent the second click of the double click from firing the `click` handler, you can do something like this:

```
function handler(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    panleft();
    $(this).unbind('click');
    setTimeout(function(){$('#buttonPanLeft').click(handler)}, 500)
}
$('#buttonPanLeft').click(handler);
```

Which prevents another click event from taking place until 500 milliseconds have elapsed.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Nmtcc/1/)

Comment: isn't that handler the  `e.preventDefault();` in the example I submitted ? thanks

Comment: @Solyaris You attached the handler to `click`, not `dblclick`.

Comment: great! finally solved with the `stopPropagation();` ! many thanks !

Comment: As of jQuery 3.0, .unbind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .off() method since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged. . source : [https://api.jquery.com/unbind/](https://api.jquery.com/unbind/)