# Double click prevented but prevent default does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am using code [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376601/jquery-how-to-disable-dblclick-events) and the double click prevention works, however the button still does not respond to `preventDefault`

Can anyone lend a hand please?

js:

```
var myBtn = $('.myLink');
var handler = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("prevent 2x click");
    $(this).unbind('click');
    setTimeout(function(){ myBtn.click(handler); }, 500);
}
myBtn.click(handler);
```

html:
`<a class='myLink' href="#">my link to click</a>`

Comment: you didn't do anything to stop propagation.

Comment: You need to do `e.stopPropagation();`

Comment: what about `e.preventDefault();` inside the handler?

Comment: that just... prevents the .. default.

Comment: If you just want to prevent double click, why not preventDefault on the double click event?

Comment: i tried `dblclick` but that did nothing

Comment: i would like to prevent the double click (and this code does that) but prevent default does not work. From this code the url gets fired from the anchor tags href

Comment: i should change the title of the question

Comment: @PSL when i jam on the button,  i get the `#` in the URL

Comment: Sorry check this ? http://jsfiddle.net/t24eM/

Comment: @PSL thank you!  i will accept this as an answer if you post this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is that when you unbind the handler(which has preventDefault) and in the small period of time one more click comes in it doesn't prevent the default behavior. So you can attach a dedicated handler to prevent default and unbind the handler that just does your other logic. Try this way:

```
var myBtn = $('.myLink');

var handler = function(e){
    $(this).unbind('click', handler); //unbind only your handler
    setTimeout(function(){
            myBtn.click(handler); }
    , 500);
}

myBtn.click(preventDefault); //have this bound to the anchor to prevent the default behavior always

myBtn.click(handler);

function preventDefault(e){
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mk8yc/)**